# No route matches POST confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very unfamiliar with routing and the entire back-end of Rails in general.  I am attempting to have a click on "edit cart" lead to the edit page, I have the edit_cart_path and corresponding view- but when I click the edit cart button, I get

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/carts/21/edit"
```

I have resources :carts in routes.rb, I have get "/carts/:id/edit" => "carts#edit" as well.  Have tried a couple other methods including "via: get".  Why is it insisting on POST, and how to solve this?

Comment: No Need of the extra route ` get "/carts/:id/edit" => "carts#edit" ` as by default rails gives you restful routes (create,edit,delete and update) through `resources` so remove that extra route and try once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing something like this, in your view:

```
button_to(edit_cart_path(@cart))
```

When using a `button_to` helper, the default HTTP method will be POST.

You'll have to do explicitly define the HTTP method you want to execute:

```
button_to(edit_cart_path(@cart), method: :get)
```

I would encourage you to use the `link_to` helper instead, and add any button effect using CSS:

```
link_to(edit_cart_path(@cart), class: 'btn')
```

From the Rails 4 documentation:

> button_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {})
>
> The options hash accepts the same options as url_for.
>
> There are a few special html_options:
>
> :method - Symbol of HTTP verb. Supported verbs are :post, :get,
>   :delete and :put. **By default it will be :post.**

Comment: Excellent.  I truly love you guys on this site.